# A question on localization

Tags: commutative-algebra

For an integral domain $R$, I know that 
$$R=\bigcap_{\text{maximal ideals }\mathcal{m}}R_{\mathcal{m}}.$$
Why must $R$ be an integral domain?

I want to know a counterexample when $R$ is not an integral domain.

Comment: This intersection notation is not even well-defined if $R$ is not an integral domain; the intersection is supposed to be taking place in $\text{Frac}(R)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p, q$ be distinct prime numbers.
Let $R = \mathbb{Z}/pq\mathbb{Z}$.
Let $m = pR$.
$\ker(R \rightarrow R_m) = \{x \in R|\ sx = 0$ for some $s \in R - m\}$.
Since $qp = 0$ in $R$ and $q \in R - m$, $p \in \ker(R \rightarrow R_m)$.
Hence $\ker(R \rightarrow R_m) \neq 0$.
So $R$ is not a subring of $R_m$.